# Trying to make a GET variable invisible in an URL but retain its usefulness using mod_write

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good day all,

I am trying to master the ,magic of mod_rewrite and require some advice/help.

I am trying to turn an URL from:

```
http://www.domainname.com/preview/about/5
```

To this:

```
http://www.domainname.com/preview/about
```

The issue is, I still need to retain the [id] part of the original URL to be used as a GET later on and it not be visible.

The code I have thus far:

```
RewriteRule ^preview\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/$         /preview\/$1?id=$2 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^preview\/([^/]+)\/$                  ?mode=preview&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This manages to create an URL like: `http://www.domainname.com/preview/about/?id=5` and passes the `ID` through, I just need the ?id=5 to be invisible in the URL.

Thank you in advance anyone who has a solution for this, much appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have managed to get the following code to work as expected alas this is using static values for ID all I now need for this to be complete is to get it working off dynamic values for ID.

```
RewriteRule ^preview\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/$       /preview\/$1      [R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond                                     %{QUERY_STRING} !.*id=5.*$
RewriteRule ^preview\/([^/]+)\/$                ?mode=preview&id=5 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You simply can not have “invisible GET parameters”, that’s a technical impossibility.

Comment: Please look at the UPDATE I have added to my question, this shows that GET parameters can be invisible, albeit the value of ID being static it still passes the GET without showing in the URL. I just need to work out how to get that static value to a dynamic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get 'invisible' get parameters. The closest you'll get is setting a cookie to pass this data onwards.

```
RewriteRule ^preview/([^/]+)/([^/]+)[/]?$ preview/$1/ [CO=id:$2:127.0.0.1:1:/preview/$1:0:1,R]
```

In php you can access this cookie with `$_COOKIE['id']` and the id is invisible in the url (because it isn't actually there). Documentation about the `CO` flag can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co).

---

Edit: If you want to do it all with mod_rewrite, you can access this cookie from mod_rewrite too. As this is an internal rewrite, you can probably just use a direct path to the actual file you want to call.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} id=([^;]*)
RewriteRule ^preview/([^/]+)[/]?$ preview/$1?id=%1 [CO=id:-:127.0.0.1:-1:/preview/$1:0:1,END]
```

Edit2: I've added in a reset for the id-cookie in the second rule (expiry time T-1 minutes). This will cause the correct page to load if the user decides to go to `preview/about/` again within 1 minute from going to `preview/about/5` (which redirects to `preview/about/` with a hidden id set to '5' to load something different).

Comment: It worked for me :-) Please note that the first rule needs to be altered (it currently makes a cookie for `127.0.0.1`. The second rule uses the `END` flag, which is only available from 2.3.9 onwards. Before that it will create an internal error.

Comment: OK, just tested this and it does not work :( I have updated the IP on line 2 and tested without `END`. One thing I noticed is the rewriteRule is appending the ?id=%1 to the end of the redirect, which we dont want to have appear. It appears that the cookie is not passing through the values.

Comment: so to help out, the URI that is being given will be like this: `http://www.domainname.com/preview/[pagename]/?id=[hashstring]` and will then require to become thus: `http://www.domainname.com/preview/[pagename]`

Comment: The first rule redirects `/preview/[pagename]/[id]/` to `/preview/[pagename]/` with a hidden `[id]`. The second rule is an *internal rewrite* (and therefore invisible to the client!) from `/preview/[pagename]/` to `/preview/[pagename]?id=[id]` internally, but the client will see `/preview/[pagename]/` as the url in the address bar. In your code you'll link to `/preview/[pagename]/[id]/`, but the client will always see `/preview/[pagename]/` as the url in the address bar. If you see `/preview/[pagename]?id=[id]` in the address bar, you have created a redirect, not an internal rewrite!

Comment: I appreciate the in depth explanation, thank you. OK, making sure the URI in the code is `/preview/[pagename]/[id]/` and using your exact code when tried, returns a 404 error and the URL still shows `/preview/[pagename]/[id]/` completely out of ideas as to why it works for you and not me.

Comment: Add `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` in httpd.conf and restart the http-deamon. Go to `/preview/[pagename]/[id]/` and then check your apache error log. It should contain information about what patterns were matched and what was rewritten. I think something messes with your url before it reaches my first rule or your htaccess is not in your www root.

Comment: .htaccess is in the root of the subdomain the site runs off, its a development domain http://[subdomain].[domain].[tld], It is also; sadly, a shared server :( and I dont think I have access to that file, I am asking that of the hosting provider now.

Comment: NOPE I cannot add that to the file. Any other ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34234/discussion-between-sumurai8-and-daniel-wrigley)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not passing the "ID" as part of the query string (e.g. `?id=5`) or part of the URI (e.g. `/preview/about/5`) then you need to pass it in the request body, in something like a POST request. Otherwise, you can't make it "invisible", because the webserver isn't going to see it. If the webserver doesn't see it as a request, there is nothing mod_rewrite can possibly do to extract it.

Assuming you can't setup your site so that requests get POSTed (sort of like how a form is submitted) everytime someone clicks on a link, you're best bet is probably having it look like the `http://www.domainname.com/preview/about/5` form, or maybe `http://www.domainname.com/preview/about-5`?

Comment: Lets say I am passing the ID as part of the string, is there anyway in which to make that invisible within the URL? I already do that when I activate my maintenance mode which passes a GET called mode but ignores that from the URL. The issue there is that I dont understand how that code does that :(

Comment: @DanielWrigley "*I already do that when I activate my maintenance mode which passes a GET called mode but ignores that from the URL. The issue there is that I dont understand how that code does that*" A session cookie?

Comment: No its only handled in the .htaccess file, the GET mode is created and passed in the mod rewrite and invisible from the URL. But as stated I know not how. It was another Stack user @Prix who helped me with that.

Comment: Also if you see my update in the OP that works 100% but uses a static value I just need that static to be dynamic that comes from the original URL and passed on.

Comment: @DanielWrigley When you rewrite a static value to a static value, that's not "hiding" anything, that's just rewriting. If you want to remove a dynamic part of the URI, the target of the rewrite isn't going to know what it is, thus you're removing it from the target as well (i.e. the `?mode=preview&id=XXX` part). How are you going to fill in the XXX? If you are rewriting `foo/foo` to `bar/bar` then both can be anything, you aren't capturing anything dynamic. But if you want `foo/<something>` to `bar/<something>`, that "something" has to be there or `bar` is not getting anything.