# htaccess - how to cut tailing number for URI and save it in a Cookie

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies, numeric

I am completely lost and all my searching on Google and winthin the board did not get me to a working solution.

**Setup**

Apache-webserver
htdocs are located: xampp/htdocs
my Joomla site is located: xampp/htdocs/example.com/www

**Two kinds of URI as possible on our homepage:**

1. URI end with a number (8 digits; e.g.: www.example.com/[any page/12345678)
2. URI does not end with a number (e.g.: www.example.com/[any page])

**If the URI ends with a number do the following**

- Read the number from the URI and place it in a cookie
- Redirect the request to the same URI except for the number
  (e.g.: www.example.com/[any page])

**If the URI does not end with a number do the following**

- Open the page as requested (e.g.: www.example.com/[any page])

I was hoping that this was not too difficult to do but I am completely lost. Would you please as to give me a little help. Please do include a statement to RewriteBase as well because it is giving me a hard time, too.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830707/trying-to-make-a-get-variable-invisible-in-an-url-but-retain-its-usefulness-usin/17859357#17859357

Comment: did my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/([0-9]{8})$ /$1 [R=301,CO=cookieName:$2:.example.com:1440:/]
```

take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co for more information about cookie flag

Comment: Great, I came up with the following rule myself:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]{8}[/]?)$ $1 [L,CO=example_cookie:$2:localhost:/:0]`
* cookie is working fine
**error.log** (Apache 2.4) tells me the replacement works but is ignored eventually
`... [rewrite:trace1] ... mod_rewrite.c(468): ... ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1d5cb48][rid#2a0f0a0/initial] [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/example.com/www/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: F:/xampp/htdocs/example.com/www/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]`
Why is that?